# Nested Cases After Action?

Tags: c#, nested, action, case

I've been having a very hard time trying to figure out how to have a sub code block that is triggered after an action. Such as:

```
       case "---":
         if (ranNum == 4)
         (First Action (Open File Path or Play Music))
                {
                  switch()
                   {
                    case: "...":
                      if (ranNum > 4)
                             (Second Action 1)
                      if (ranNum < 1)
                             (Second Action 2)
                    break;
                    case: "///":
                      if (ranNum > 4)
                             (Third Action 1)
                      if (ranNum < 1)
                             (Third Action 2) 
                    break;
                   }    

                }
       break;
```

The difficulty here us that once (First Action (Open File Path or Play Music)) is activated, the code jumps strait down to the bottom break;. It completely ignores the two possible nested cases. I'm still fairly new to C# so this issue has been driving me nuts for weeks. Does anyone know how to make the code go to the nested case options after (First Action (Open File Path or Play Music))? And yes (First Action) does open a type of file path.

Comment: So is `(First Action (Open File Path or Play Music))` part of the `if` statement, or the code to be used in it?

Comment: And the answer is to put `(First Action (Open File Path or Play Music))` inside the `{`.

Comment: `switch()` What are you exactly switching on? Also, `case: "///":` the first colon after `case` is not valid. Is that a typo?

Comment: you should post your **actual code**, posting some kind of **pseudo code** this way may not reflect the correct situation.

Comment: Post a *compilable* example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as a "nested case."  The compiler doesn't really care that it's nested.  It's going to execute whatever code is there.  The `switch` structure would generally look like this:

```
switch (someValue)
{
    case "value1":
        // some block of code
        break;
    case "value2":
        // another block of code
        break;
}
```

Whatever happens to be in `// some block of code` is irrelevant to the `switch` itself.  However, if this nesting is starting to make the code difficult to read/understand/support, then a little refactoring can clean that up a lot.  Perhaps `// some block of code` should just be a call to a separate method:

```
switch (someValue)
{
    case "value1":
        SomeMethod();
        break;
    case "value2":
        AnotherMethod();
        break;
}
```

The idea here is to:

1. Reduce excessive indentation, making the code more readable
2. Extract levels of abstraction, making the logic more clear
3. Reduce the number of things any given method does to *one*.  That is, `SomeMethod` does one thing, `AnotherMethod` does one thing, the method which contains this `switch` statement does one thing (where that one thing happens to be determining which next thing to do).